# What folders on Android besides /sdcard, com.android.. telephony and contacts should be backed up to preserve common data?

Tags: adb, backup

I want to wipe my phone but backup as much data as possible that is stored on the phone itself. I can restore applications but things such as photos, SMS text messages, and some contacts are store on the phone and not synced with Google.

I am using ADB to backup to copy the folders `/sdcard`, `/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony`, `/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.contacts`.

Am I missing any Android or Google data that might be stored exclusively on the phone (excluding anything from the Google Play Store).

`com.android.providers.telephony` contains SMS text messages and `com.android.providers.contacts` contains any contacts that are on the phone that are not synced with Google.

I am using Lineage OS 14 (Android 7.1.2).

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763

Comment: some apps will store stuff in */data/media/obb* and some apps using TEE keystore. also check */data/user/0*